# How to open mongo-db dump file?

Tags: database, mongodb, dump, mongorestore

I have a .dump file (8GB) which is a mongo database that I need to work with. 
I'm working with Robo 3T.

I've tried:

- a) menu options in robo gui
- b) `mongorestore --db cert-db certctream.dump` command, got error
  (using certctream without the extension didn't work as well)

> Failed: file certctream.dump does not have .bson extension

What am I missing?

Comment: `mongorestore --host localhost:27017 path_to_your_dump_file `

Comment: Failed: file C:\Users\yehonata\Desktop\certctream.dump does not have .bson extension

As I said - it's a dump file

Comment: you need to put path upto your dump folder... because mongodump doesn't out with the `.dump` extension...

Comment: I don't understand what is the solution you suggest... this command doesn't work with or without the extension. My file is .dump file. Is there a way to deal with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
mongoimport --db <new_db_name> --host localhost:27017 path_to_dump_file
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To import a mongo collection:

   ```
   mongoimport -d database_name -c collection_name
   ```

   In this case, `collection_name` would be the JSON file for the corresponding collection.
2. To import a mongo database:

   ```
   mongorestore -d database_name
   ```

   In this case, `database_name` would be a folder.

Answer (score 0):

To restore from a `.dump` file you need to use the `archive` argument:

```
mongorestore --archive=mydump.dump
```

**GOTCHA**
The dump may have also been gzipped, in which case you'll get:
`Failed: stream or file does not appear to be a mongodump archive`

In this case, try adding `--gzip` as it might do the job:

```
mongorestore --gzip --archive=mydump.dump
```